# Tilemap composite collider 2D will not interact with player collider 2d

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-physics, game-development

Unity Version: 2019.4.36f1

So the game is a 2D platformer. I set a tilemap and I used tilemap collider 2d then I checked the box "Used By Composite". The player would collide with the original tilemap collider 2D, but will not collide when the composite collider is active.

When I changed the "Geometry Type" to polygon at the composite collider, it worked.

Players Rigitbody2D is dynamic and tilemap (auto-generated from composite collider 2D) Rigitbody2D is static because it's the ground.

Can someone explain why this is happening? I searched the web and I can't find a solution.